# POST base 64 image string to a server on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, base64, indico

To my understanding, to use this website I have to convert an image to a base64 encoded image and then send it to this website. The website will then send me back a number (as a decimal).

https://docs.indico.io/docs/rest-api-image-analysis

I've tried using a number of steps, namely trying to alter a similar process used for sending text and receiving a number. Any tips?

UPDATE:

```
 - (IBAction)press:(id)sender {

    //UIImage *imager = photos.image;

 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photos.image, 1.0);
    NSString *base64Img = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];

    //not sure if @"data" or @"data.json" and whether the base64img should be behind it
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"data":base64Img};

    NSMutableString *parameterString = [NSMutableString string];
    for (NSString *key in [parameters allKeys]) {
        if ([parameterString length]) {
            [parameterString appendString:@"&"];
        }
        [parameterString appendFormat:@"%@=%@", key, parameters[key]];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apiv2.indico.io/contentfiltering?key='17767cb46eb4b4f568832be2c953022b"];
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:[parameterString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                if ([data length]) {
                    NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                    //GET RESULT;
                    NSLog(@"A %@", parameters[@"results"]);

                }

            } else {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }
        }];
        [task resume];

    }
```

the results I get usually return as `(null)`

Comment: what part are you stuck on exactly? post any relevant code that you have tried so far

Comment: if you put a breakpoint just after your request object is made, copy paste the url from the request object into your browser and see if the response is something you are expecting, otherwise your url is probably constructed incorrectly

Comment: it seems like your request body is not in a json format, you might have to JSONSerialize your `parameters` dictionary instead of trying to url encode it

Comment: @robert I notice you have a single quote before your key in the url (param). That shouldn't be there right? esp if there's no corresponding closing quote.

Answer (score 4):

maybe try going

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"data":base64Img};

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters
                   options:nil
                     error:&error];

//do some error checking

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apiv2.indico.io/contentfiltering?key='17767cb46eb4b4f568832be2c953022b"];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

//...
```

just doing this off the top of my head so may need some tweaking

Comment: i'll give it a shot and see what happens :)

Comment: i get a thread 1.1 breakpoint at `NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters`

Comment: does it give any useful error on that line? seems weird

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess it looks like you've accidentally added a typo to your API key. In the line above:

```
http://apiv2.indico.io/contentfiltering?key='17767cb46eb4b4f568832be2c953022b
```

should instead read:

```
http://apiv2.indico.io/contentfiltering?key=17767cb46eb4b4f568832be2c953022b
```

Since URL parameters are sometimes quoted and I'm not extremely familiar with objective-c's internal request handling I would guess that that is leading to the strange behavior you're seeing.